# VS2010 Locking up my keyboard (or at least parts of it)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard, locking

I am having a problem with VS2010 randomly disabling certain keys like my arrow and backspace keys when editing files in stored in VSS.  It seemed to have just started happening the other day, but simply restarting VS would fix the problem and it may come back a day or two later.  Now I restart and it lasts maybe 10 minutes or until I open another file before it comes back.  Is there some known issue causing this that there might be a fix for?

Mike

Comment: Sounds like a virus issue from the past!

Comment: I haven't had any virus issues on this machine since it' been reformatted and reinstalled.

Comment: Does this *only* happen for files stored in VSS. If so, have you considered trying anything other than VSS? (There are also many other good reasons to stop using VSS today.)

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't noticed it on any other projects not using VSS.  I read somewhere that resetting my settings using the Import/Export settings might help. I'm trying that to see if it gets any better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've heard various reports of this, but we're having a *really* hard time tracking it down.  Please file a bug on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) with as much information as you can give: file types, your project or some project you can repro it with (if possible, I know that can be tough), any more steps you can think of other than what you've posted here, extensions/packages/add-ons you have installed, etc.

If you are curious, the underlying cause is related to the command system in the shell.  In general, it tries to keep the focused element and the active command target in sync, but there are cases where it falls apart.  When that happens, commands (like return and backspace) stop working, though normal typing tends to continue to work (as the text input events are handled in the focused editor window anyways).  The difficult part of debugging it is that by the time you get into the state, it's too late to figure out *why* focus/activation got out of sync.  We're hoping to improve the diagnosability of this in the future, as well as possibly a helper that just sits around and synchronizes focus/activation periodically.

Comment: Thanks Noah, I will try and work on that.  As mentioned above I reset my settings and haven't had the issue reappear as of yet.  If it starts happening again I will try and provide as much info as possible in a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happening since VS2005..
randomly my backspace will stop working.. 
If I closed VS and reopend it starts working again.. never got to the bottom of it tho, let me know if you work out what's happening as resetting maybe fixes it for abit, but then it breaks again.